# Is there a way to rename an external hard drive?

Tags: 11.10, external-hdd, rename

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and I have a couple of WD external drives.  The problem is, they all show up in the file manager as "Elements" which can get confusing.  Is there a way to rename one or both of them?  Right-clicking and going to properties didn't yield any results.

Comment: You can use the `ntfslabel` tool if the file system on the external disk drive is NTFS.

Comment: `ntfslabel /dev/sdb1 Windows`, `ntfslabel /dev/sdb5 Porno`

Comment: Don't forget to throw a `sudo` on there too. So `sudo ntfslabel /dev/sdc1 Windows`

Comment: @shawn did any of the advices work for you? I also have a WD Elements and changing the partition label doesn't do the trick. It is still shown as *Elements*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "Disk Utility" tool that ships with most Ubuntu installations lets you change volume labels quite easily.

As with any disk operation, I would recommend performing a backup of the device first :-)

There is a duplicated question, see more [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/710487/450832)

Comment: The option is called 'Edit Filesystem...' (Linux Mint 19)

Answer (score 23):

The label is a property of the drive's filesystem itself - you need to modify that using GParted or other tools. Here are some instructions in [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive):

- Open the System > Administration menu and see if there's an entry for GParted (previously Partition Editor).
- If there is, launch it. If there isn't, install the "gparted" package and it should now appear in the menu. Enter your password when prompted.
- Disk drives are divided up into partitions. To find the partition you want to re-label, you first have to find the disk drive that contains it, using the drop-down menu in the upper right. It will show a device name like /dev/sdb and the drive's total size in parentheses. After selecting a drive, you will see a list of all partitions on that drive.
- If the partition is mounted (has a key icon next to it), right-click on the partition and select Unmount.
- With the key icon gone, right-click on the partition and select Label. If you can't select it, install the ntfsprogs package.
- Enter the new partition name and press Ok.
- The label change is now pending, but has not been completed. Press the Apply button near the top of the window. After confirming, it should say "All operations successfully completed". The drive now has a new label.

Answer (score 6):

With Ubuntu 13.04 search for Disks.  Select the disk. Below the Volumes box, click the square button to unmount the disk. The square will change to triangle (Mount). Then click the More Options button and select Edit Filesystem Label... Edit the name, select Change and then mount the drive by clicking the  Mount button.

Not as easy as Windows, but manageable

Answer (score 5):

Use the Disk Utility Provided by ubuntu.
For Ubuntu 15.10.
Search Disks in the Dashboard.
Open Disks-> Click on the settings of the required hard drive.-> Edit File Sytem->change the required name.

Note: Unmount(by clicking on the stop icon) the drive before you change the Labels.

Comment: this worked for me for Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu Ver 20.04.2, there is built-in application called 'Disks'.

- Find it from search bar
- Select the Disk Drive you want to rename
- Click 'Additional partition options' (with gear-wheel icon)
- Choose 'Edit Filesystem'
- Rename the label (Disk name) as you like, and Click 'Change'

Hope it helps!

Comment: If you forget to unmount the drive beforehand like I did, unmount then remount the drive.  This changes the name in /media/<user name>

Comment: Thanks - nice and simple.

Answer (score 2):

If your disk uses NTFS then you can rename it with

```
sudo ntfslabel /dev/sdc1 New_disk_name
```

(Replace 'sdc1' with the folder your disk is using.)